# Can e.g. be used in the end of a sentence in place of "for example"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

It is said that **e.g.** (informally also written as eg.) is a abbreviated Latin phrase used in place of "*for example*".

Reference: [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e.g.), [here](http://public.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/e.g.html) & [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exempli_gratia#exempli_gratia)

Example:

> **Asia is a large continent containing many large nations (For example, China, India and Russia).**
>
> can also be written as the following by replacing "**For example**" by "**e.g**"
>
> **Asia is a large continent containing many large nations (e.g., China, India and Russia).**

Is this "replacement" also valid when used in a case like this:

> ... and that is why Democratic countries often end up with higher rate of corruption. Take US & India for example.

Can the last sentence of above example be rewritten as:

> Take US & India e.g.

**P.S.**

I know that somehow it is incorrect but I am not aware of the reason.

Comment: No. In this case, use English: *for example* as it is. Use the abbreviation *e.g.,* (not *eg.*) **before** a list of examples, as in the earlier sentence.

Comment: Or you can find a style guide allowing eg without the full stops (though I've never found one recommending the terminal usage you ask about). Remember that guides are guides, not the Ten Commandments, and always be wary when you meet a guideline saying 'Do it this way [ie the way that _I_ prefer]'. I can even point you to one saying you shouldn't use these so-called 'Latin abbreviations' (e.g. / eg. /eg; op cit; etc; et al . . .) at all.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that 'Take US and India for example' is not a complete sentence anyway, regardless of the e.g./for example argument.

Comment: @bamboo In what way is it not a complete sentence? The use of 'take' for 'consider' is allowable, and the 'for example' is a parenthetical, a pragmatic phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the relevant information seems already to be in this thread, so this is "icing" on the pre-existing "cake".

The *reason* that "e.g." should *introduce* a list rather than *terminate* the giving of an example lies in the Latin itself. "exempli" = "(an) example", "gratia" = "for the sake of". The natural sense, then, is to supply a helpfulexample or examples (but not exhaustive list) for something just mentioned.

"For example" is a common gloss for the Latin "exempli gratia", but not a precise translation. "E.g.", then, shouldn't simply be used wherever "for example" can be used.

In short, and to cite the authority of Brian Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage* (OUP, 2009), [p. 295](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mVcJqKs1isUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA295#v=onepage&q&f=false), "e.g. **introduces** representative examples" (emphasis added). One might add, by implication, "it doesn't conclude them".

Comment: No; the reason that "e.g." should introduce a list rather than terminate the giving of an example lies in the fact that that's the way it's almost always used today. As Garner says. Appeals to Latin as justifications are almost invariably examples of the etymological fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

No; 'e. g.' is to be used preceding a list of examples, but you cannot use it to replace the words 'for example' when they are simply the words which terminate a sentence.  See [this page](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/abbreviations/f/ievseg.htm) for details on both 'e. g.' and its oft-conflated cousin, 'i. e.'

Comment: You are right. Find some authentic source that says so, and, presto! you've got the 'answer'. (My comment is *not* an authentic source lol.)

Comment: Will that link do?

Comment: That doesn't seem to explain the present case.